# CORS on Spring-OAuth2

Tags: spring-rest, spring-oauth2

I am using Spring-Boot and Spring-OAuth2 to protect my Rest APIs.  I have implemented OAuth2. It gets executed properly. I developed AngularJS and try to access it, but I am getting CORS error.

**Error** -> `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://192.168.2.45:8080/Jaihind/oauth/token. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).`

**URL** -> `curl -X POST -vu clientapp:123456 http://localhost:8080/Jaihind/oauth/token -H "Accept: application/json" -d "password=password&username=gaurav&grant_type=password&scope=read%20write&client_secret=123456&client_id=clientapp"`

Below are the codes.

**OAuth2ServerConfiguration.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class OAuth2ServerConfiguration {

    private static final String RESOURCE_ID = "restservice";

    @Configuration
    @EnableResourceServer

    protected static class ResourceServerConfiguration extends
            ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
            // @formatter:off
            resources.resourceId(RESOURCE_ID);
            // @formatter:on
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

            // @formatter:off
            http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/greeting").authenticated();
            http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/oauth/token").permitAll();
            //http.antMatcher("/oauth/token").p

            // @formatter:on
        }

    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableAuthorizationServer
    protected static class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

        private TokenStore tokenStore = new InMemoryTokenStore();

        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
        private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

        @Autowired
        private UserDetailServiceBean userDetailsService;

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
            // @formatter:off

            endpoints.addInterceptor(new HandlerInterceptorAdapter() {
                @Override
                public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest hsr, HttpServletResponse rs, Object o) throws Exception {
                    rs.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
                    rs.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,POST,OPTIONS");
                    rs.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers,Authorization");
                    return true;
                }
            });
            endpoints.tokenStore(this.tokenStore)
                    .authenticationManager(this.authenticationManager)
                    .userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
            // @formatter:on
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
            // @formatter:off
            clients
                    .inMemory()
                    .withClient("clientapp")
                    .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token")
                    .authorities("USER")
                    .scopes("read", "write")
                    .resourceIds(RESOURCE_ID)
                    .secret("123456");
            // @formatter:on
        }

        @Bean
        @Primary
        public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
            DefaultTokenServices tokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
            tokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
            tokenServices.setTokenStore(this.tokenStore);
            return tokenServices;
        }

    }
}
```

I even added Filter.

```
Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class YourCORSFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp,
                         FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) resp;
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;

        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type,x-auth-token,x-requested-with,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers,Authorization");
        if (request.getMethod() != "OPTIONS") {
            chain.doFilter(req, resp);
        } else {
        }

        chain.doFilter(req, resp);
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

}
```

Comment: Hello Anyone please update me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your filter always calls `chain.doFilter(req, resp)` so if the downstream app doesn't handle the CORS requests then you are going to see errors like that.

Comment: Hello What can be the solution for this.. I have followed https://github.com/royclarkson/spring-rest-service-oauth

Comment: I have removed this filter and added the web.xml with the details - https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html . I have also configured Application.java with Spring-CORS. But still I am getting error. I have followed - https://github.com/royclarkson/spring-rest-service-oauth for Spring-OAuth2. So kindly assist me.

Comment: If it's a Spring Boot application then `web.xml` is no use to you. You just need to fix the filter (although I wouldn't recommend going into production with it in that form, that's another topic entirely). Example filter that works: https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/blob/master/vanilla/resource/src/main/groovy/demo/CorsFilter.groovy).

Comment: Actually I need to deploy it on external tomcat server. But the code you shared also has the CORSFilter implemented , so sir what is the difference. Also what should be i doing in production. Second, do i need to implement CsrfTokenRepository?

Comment: Spring Boot apps do not have a `web.xml` (it's pretty simple). The difference with the filter I linked to was that it doesn't always call `chain.doFilter(req, resp)` (as I already said).

Comment: I tried this, but I am still getting CORS with 401 on /oauth/token

Comment: Permanent link to old code: https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/blob/35e00f17d9c1354b83edfdc78963f22222d96a1d/vanilla/resource/src/main/groovy/demo/CorsFilter.groovy. It's obsolete now that Spring Security supports Spring MVC CORS declarations.